# Структура приложения PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

Здравствуйте. Хотелось бы попросить совета, как правильно организовать структуру приложения. Я только учусь разработке на PHP. Не судите строго.

Задание такое, необходимо создать приложение в котором пользователи могут общаться между собой. Будет личный кабинет пользователя, и будет админка, где админ может видеть всех пользователей на сайте.

Не могу представить в голове структуру. На данный момент Вижу только такое:

[image: Структура в PHP Storm]

По папкам:

1. *auth* - Страница авторизации;
2. *profile* - Страница с личным кабинетом, куда пользователь попадет после авторизации;
3. *templates* - header.php,footer.php и остальные файлы, все они будут, как шаблон сайта
4. *core* - предположительно ядро, и через эту папку можно будет войти в админку;
5. *lib* - другие функции...

Вот из этого вопрос, как лучше организовать это.

Comment: index должен быть в отдельной подпапке. общая конвенция правил именования содержится в PSR-4

Comment: Почему бы не посмотреть в сторону 'mvc`?

Answer (score 3):

У меня обычно для несложных приложений с нуля структура, позаимствованная из систем пэкиджей Linux и Windows, некоторый микс:

1. В приложении есть модули
2. Каждый модуль хранится в своей папке (это список папок, а не дерево)
3. В этой папке есть подпапки, например, php, css, js, html, tpl
4. Любое обращение, за исключением запросов к файлам (картинкам), производится только к одному скрипту: `index.php`, в котором настраивается autoload.
5. Чтобы к `index.php` нельзя было обратиться напрямую, в файле `.htaccess` с помощью mod_rewrite задается переменная MODULE c соответствующим значением, например, `admin` или `frontend` (это названия модулей), которая будет видна в массиве `$_SERVER`
6. Усли у заданного модуля есть контроллер, хоторый лежит в файле modulename/php/Ctrl.php, то index.php созздает экземпляр этого контроллера и запускает.

Довольно удобно для небольших приложений без фреймворка, поскольку сразу понятно, какой файл где искать, в отличие от структур, в которых кучи однотипных файлов разных модулей свалены в одну папку, что требует еще и наличие установщика модулей.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите как это организовано в популярных фреймворках. Например:

- https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic
- https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced
- https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

Да тот же 1С-Битрикс установите - посмотрите структуру как делать не стоит или наоборот стоит (тут на вкус и цвет...) ;)

А лучше на основе фреймворка и делать проект. Когда над вашим проектом будут работать другие люди - за самописное решение большого спасибо не скажут.

Именованием файлов, стайлгайд, автолоадер и т.д. обратите внимание на http://www.php-fig.org/psr/.

Если возникнет вопрос: а что изучать? Смотрите и отталкивайтесь от вакансий - что требуется и что чаще, а также вилку ЗП.

И не PHP едины - это главное не забывайте.

Comment: Постараюсь завтра ответ дополнить - с мобилы сейчас сижу.

Comment: Я еще просто не могу понять саму суть mvc, можно ли в mvc использовать структуру, как в том же 1С-Битрикс из папок.

Comment: @j.doe по [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) базовое определение вы можете прочитать в той же wiki. Если вы будете писать самописный движок и CMS — то как вы сделаете структуру уже ваш выбор. Будете ли вы предерживаться шаблона MVC или нет, и как вы его интерпретируете — тоже. Дело в том, что если вы будете использовать тот же шаблон MVC в своем проекте — вам самому и другим разработчикам, которые будут работать с вашим кодом — будет проще. Так как с этим шаблоном они могут быть уже знакомы.

Comment: @j.doe Если же в работе будете использовать какой-нибудь фреймворк — общая структура и шаблоны будут уже «заданы». На то они и фреймворки.

Comment: @j.doe например, [вот](https://selftaughtcoders.com/from-idea-to-launch/lesson-17/laravel-5-mvc-application-in-10-minutes/) или [zend-mvc](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-mvc/intro/). Но у Zend Framework документация больше техническая и на английском.